# Merge several Excel sheets with overlapping data

Tags: python, excel, sqlite

I have several Excel files describing road network. Let's take 3 for example (actual files are rather large and with way more records):

Describing pavement:

```
Road From To Pavement
    X 0,00 1,00 Asphalt
    X 1,00 3,53 Gravel
    X 3,53 5,00 Asphalt
```

Describing quality:

```
Road From To Quality
    X 0,00 1,50 Fine
    X 1,50 4,00 Poor
    X 4,00 5,00 Satisfactory
```

Describing traffic volume:

```
 Road From To Traffic
     X 0,00 1,20 3055
     X 1,20 2,80 1040
     X 2,80 5,00 3600
```

I want to merge all these files and to get a result with all data possible (divided in more sections obviously). Like this:

```
Road From To Quality Pavement Traffic
    X 0,00 1,00 Fine Asphalt 3055
    X 1,00 1,20 Fine Gravel 3055
    X 1,20 1,50 Fine Gravel 1040
    X 1,50 2,80 Poor Gravel 1040
    X 2,80 3,53 Poor Gravel 3600
    X 3,53 4,00 Poor Asphalt 3600
    X 4,00 5,00 Satisfactory Asphalt 3600
```

No idea how to do that. Tried to read all available data with openpyxl (Python) to gather all the data in Sqlite database but no I idea how to select the data properly. Tried sorting, grouping and nothing so far.
Any ideas?

Comment: Have you successfully read the data from all excels and inserted them Sqlite? If so, share all the table structure with snapshot of few records from each?

Comment: Create a column as a key column and concatenate the Road, From and To to make one value, do that in all sheets and then use vlookup to get values from all sheets to one sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's get usable sqlite tables out of that sample:

```sql
CREATE TABLE pavement(road TEXT, from_mile NUMERIC, to_mile NUMERIC, pavement TEXT);
INSERT INTO pavement VALUES('X',0,1,'Asphalt');
INSERT INTO pavement VALUES('X',1,3.5299999999999998046,'Gravel');
INSERT INTO pavement VALUES('X',3.5299999999999998046,5,'Asphalt');
CREATE TABLE quality(road TEXT, from_mile NUMERIC, to_mile NUMERIC, quality TEXT);
INSERT INTO quality VALUES('X',0,1.5,'Fine');
INSERT INTO quality VALUES('X',1.5,4,'Poor');
INSERT INTO quality VALUES('X',4,5,'Satisfactory');
CREATE TABLE traffic(road TEXT, from_mile NUMERIC, to_mile NUMERIC, traffic INTEGER);
INSERT INTO traffic VALUES('X',0,1.1999999999999999555,3055);
INSERT INTO traffic VALUES('X',1.1999999999999999555,2.7999999999999998223,1040);
INSERT INTO traffic VALUES('X',2.7999999999999998223,5,3600);
CREATE INDEX pavement_idx_road_from ON pavement(road, from_mile);
CREATE INDEX quality_idx_road_from ON quality(road, from_mile);
CREATE INDEX traffic_idx_road_from ON traffic(road, from_mile);
```

Now that we have something to work with, the first step is to get the mileage intervals from all three tables (Note: This requires sqlite 3.25 or newer because it uses a window function):

```sql
SELECT road, from_mile
     , lead(from_mile, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY road ORDER BY from_mile) AS to_mile
FROM (SELECT road, from_mile FROM pavement
      UNION
      SELECT road, from_mile FROM quality
      UNION
      SELECT road, from_mile FROM traffic
      UNION
      SELECT road, max(to_mile) FROM pavement GROUP BY road);
```

gives us

```
road        from_mile   to_mile   
----------  ----------  ----------
X           0           1         
X           1           1.2       
X           1.2         1.5       
X           1.5         2.8       
X           2.8         3.53      
X           3.53        4         
X           4           5
X           5           (null)
```

Basically, it gets every unique `from_mile` from the three tables and uses the next value in order as the end point `to_mile` to mark what will be a unique section in the final results.

The next step is to take those rows and join them against all three tables to get the needed fields for each mileage interval:

```sql
WITH ranges AS
  (SELECT road, from_mile
        , lead(from_mile, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY road ORDER BY from_mile) AS to_mile
  FROM (SELECT road, from_mile FROM pavement
        UNION
        SELECT road, from_mile FROM quality
        UNION
        SELECT road, from_mile FROM traffic
        UNION
        SELECT road, max(to_mile) FROM pavement GROUP BY road))
SELECT r.road, r.from_mile, r.to_mile, q.quality, p.pavement, t.traffic
FROM ranges AS r
JOIN pavement AS p ON r.road = p.road AND p.from_mile <= r.from_mile AND p.to_mile >= r.to_mile
JOIN quality AS q ON r.road = q.road AND q.from_mile <= r.from_mile AND q.to_mile >= r.to_mile
JOIN traffic AS t ON r.road = t.road AND t.from_mile <= r.from_mile AND t.to_mile >= r.to_mile
ORDER BY r.road, r.from_mile;
```

which gives:

```
road        from_mile   to_mile     quality     pavement    traffic   
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
X           0           1           Fine        Asphalt     3055      
X           1           1.2         Fine        Gravel      3055      
X           1.2         1.5         Fine        Gravel      1040      
X           1.5         2.8         Poor        Gravel      1040      
X           2.8         3.53        Poor        Gravel      3600      
X           3.53        4           Poor        Asphalt     3600      
X           4           5           Satisfacto  Asphalt     3600
```

(Don't mind the truncation of long fields in the display; that's just how the sqlite3 shell I'm copying from formats things)

Comment: Everything works well until one of the lists has some gap. Let's say - pavement from 3.0 to 3.53 is not gravel but something else and is not showed in the list. In such case results will be weird - something will be missing. The first SELECT has to be modified but unfortunately I can't manage to do that :( Any ideas?